# Font-dislay: swap и смещение макета

Tags: css

Проблема заключается в следующем.

Задал подключение пользовательского шрифта и свойство font-display: swap

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
font-display: swap;
src: url(fonts/roboto_condensed/RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf) format('truetype')
}
```

Также задал загрузку второго шрифта системного а также его масштабирование:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Adjusted Arial';
  size-adjust: 89%; 
  src: local("Arial");
}

body {font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', 'Adjusted Arial', sans-serif;}
```

Когда грузится второй шрифт смещение макета не происходит. Но при загрузке страницы все-равно происходит смещение (похоже на то, что шрифт не масштабируется при загрузке страницы).

В чем может быть проблема? Есть ли возможность этого избежать?